# How to fix broken SOLR4 in Alfresco 5.0.c (Community Edition) ?

Tags: alfresco, solr4

I accidentally deleted the **solr4.xml** file located inside **tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost** and since then solr stopped working. I tried many methods like restoring solr4.xml file , solr4 full reindexing, generating new keystore but still it doesnt work.

Please suggest how can i fix my broken solr4 without new fresh installation  of alfresco.

Comment: May be your tomcat/webapps/solr4.war is not exploded properly. Try correctly configuring solr4.xml, delete solr4 folder in tomcat/webapps/ and restart tomcat.

Comment: Woops. I guess you don't have a back up? If you've replaced it then it should be working fine after a reindex, I guess something else is missing/misconfigured. Can you give us any errors from the logs?

Comment: for 5.XX community should work that
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr-reindex.html

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the procedure reported here: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr-reindex.html

- Shut down Alfresco (all nodes, if clustered).
- Shut down Solr 4 (if running on a separate application server).
- Delete the contents of the index data directories for each Solr core at ${data.dir.root}/${data.dir.store}.
  /alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/SpacesStore
  /alf_data/solr4/index/archive/SpacesStore
- Delete all the Alfresco models for each Solr 4 core at ${data.dir.root}.
  /alf_data/solr4/model
- Delete the contents of the /alf_data/solr4/content directory.
- Start up the application server that runs Solr 4.
- Start up the Alfresco application server (if not same as Solr 4 application server).
  It worked in our environment.

**Update:**
This procedure works in most cases but after a situation where the system ran out of space left on device, the system remained in a unstable state and we were forced to restore a backup.

Comment: Give the important parts of the answer, instead of giving only the link

Comment: you should just delete the full solr4 directory and backup dir under alf_data

Answer (score 1):

1. Confirm the location of the Solr 4 core directories for
   archive-SpacesStore and workspace-SpacesStore cores. This can be
   determined from the solrcore.properties file for both the cores. By
   default, the solrcore.propertiesfile can be found at
   /solr4/workspace-SpacesStore/conf or
   /solr4/archive-SpacesStore/conf. The Solr 4 core
   location is defined in the solrcore.properties file as: For Solr 4,
   the default data.dir.root path is:

   data.dir.root=/alf_data/solr4/indexes/
2. Shut down Alfresco (all nodes, if clustered).
3. Shut down Solr 4 (if running on a separate application server).
   Delete the contents of the index data directories for each Solr core
   at ${data.dir.root}/${data.dir.store}.

> /alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/SpacesStore
>
> /alf_data/solr4/index/archive/SpacesStore

Delete all the Alfresco models for each Solr 4 core at ${data.dir.root}.
/alf_data/solr4/model

1. Delete the contents of the /alf_data/solr4/content
   directory.
2. Start up the application server that runs Solr 4.
3. Start up the Alfresco application server (if not same as Solr 4
   application server).
4. Monitor the application server logs for Solr. You will get the
   following warning messages on bootstrap:

> WARNING: [alfresco] Solr index directory
>   '/alf_data/solr/workspace/SpacesStore/index' doesn't
>   exist. Creating new index... 09-May-2012 09:23:42
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent inform WARNING:
>   No queryConverter defined, using default converter 09-May-2012
>   09:23:42 org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore initIndex WARNING: [archive]
>   Solr index directory
>   '/alf_data/solr/archive/SpacesStore/index' doesn't
>   exist. Creating new index...

1. Use the Solr 4 administration console to check the health of the
   Solr 4 index.